# php library that can merge stylesheet with inline style

Tags: php, css

I am working with html document generated from Micrsoft Word 2007/2010.  Besides generating incredibly dirty html, word also has the tendency of using both  block and inline style.  I am looking for a php library would merge  block into already existing inline style element.

**Edit**
The goal is to construct a html block preserve the original formatting and editable in WYSIWYG editor like tinyMCE

**Example**

If the original html is:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .normaltext {color:black;font-weight:normal;font-size:10pt}
    .important {color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:11pt}
    </style>
    <body>
    <p class="normaltext" style="font-family:arial">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
In ut erat id dui mollis faucibus. Mauris eu neque et eros tempus placerat. 
<span class="important">Nam in purus nisi</span>, vitae dictum ligula. 
Morbi mattis eros eget diam vulputate imperdiet. 
<span class="important" style="color:green">Integer</span> a metus eros. 
Sed iaculis porta imperdiet.
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Should become:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <p style="font-family:arial;color:black;font-weight:normal;font-size:10pt">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    In ut erat id dui mollis faucibus. Mauris eu neque et eros tempus placerat. 
    <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:11pt">Nam in purus nisi</span>, vitae dictum ligula. 
    Morbi mattis eros eget diam vulputate imperdiet. 
    <span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;font-size:11pt">Integer</span> a metus eros. 
    Sed iaculis porta imperdiet.
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So you're trying to get rid of the CSS blocks and move all of it inline? Or the other way around?

Comment: The value of this is questionable. It's a complex task since it requires full DOM and CSS parsers and it's likely to lead to considerably more bloat than you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it to work.  The code is based off of
http://blog.verkoyen.eu/blog/p/detail/convert-css-to-inline-styles-with-php
with once simple change:
Moving the line

```
// add new properties into the list
foreach($rule['properties'] as $key => $value) $properties[$key] = $value;
```

up to the begining of the loop, right after where $properties is declared.

To make this work for WordPress however, one additional change is needed.  DomDocument replace &nbps; from the document with blanks, which breaks WordPress update statement and lead to cotent being cut off.  Please refer to my other question for the solution:
[DOMDocument->saveHTML() converting &nbsp; to space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114627/domdocument-savehtml-converting-nbsp-to-space)

This problem is detailed in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48692/post-content-getting-cut-off-on-blank-space-on-wpdb-update.  If you know why this is happening for WordPress, please post your answer there as I would very much like to find out why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

- http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/
- http://premailer.dialect.ca/
- http://www.pelagodesign.com/sidecar/emogrifier/
- http://blog.verkoyen.eu/blog/p/detail/convert-css-to-inline-styles-with-php
- http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css
- http://burrowscode.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/emailify-internal-stylesheets-to-inline-styles/
- https://github.com/crcn/emailify
- https://github.com/peterbe/premailer

Porting code from either of the sources to PHP, or using any of the available APIs should do the trick of getting your CSS styling inline.

Comment: Thanks, emogrifier seems very close.  Will try to play with it.  Already tried http://blog.verkoyen.eu/blog/p/detail/convert-css-to-inline-styles-with-php and doesn't merge style.

Answer (score 1):

See the [CssToInlineStyles](https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles) project which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, but try this instead, copying and pasting from word into http://ckeditor.com/ or tinymce, etc does clean it up A LOT, thought it's still not perfect it will get you much closer.