# DOMDocument->saveHTML() converting &nbsp; to space

Tags: php, domdocument, html-entities

In my code, I have

```
$document = DomDocument->loadHTML($someHTML);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($document);
//
//do some xpath query and processing
//
$result = $document->saveHTML();
```

The html I am processing contains  :

```
<html>
<body>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal;text-autospace:none"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"ArialNarrow","sans-serif";
color:red'>&nbsp;</span></b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and results in:

```
<html>
<body>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal;text-autospace:none"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"ArialNarrow","sans-serif";
color:red'> </span></b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I prevent `&nbsp;` from getting converted to blank space?

Comment: What kind of xpath and processing are you doing that the entity get's removed? Are you using normalize space or something similar?

Comment: Probably related: [PHP DOMNode entities and nodeValue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752434/php-domnode-entities-and-nodevalue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace &nbsp; with &amp;nbsp;
then when the htmlDom doc is read it will return &nbsp;

Comment: The result is that &amp;nbsp; is left on the page.

Comment: Good iidea though.  I end up doing two replace to make it work.  Replace &nbsp; with @nbsp; at the begining, and replace @nbsp; with &nbsp; at the end.

Comment: Can you explain and suggest an alternative?

Comment: Well actually you have found out that it does not work (because it did not replace that). Alternative: I was not able so far to create an example, but you are looking for [`DOMEntityReference`](http://php.net/domentityreference.construct), either manually or via xpath ([which might not be possible](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#EntityReferences)).

Comment: Also if the output is UTF-8 the "space" you see might be a non-breaking space. You should provide a hex-dump of your output to further look into it.

Answer (score 4):

```
$someHTML = str_replace ('&nbsp;', '@nbsp;', $someHTML);
$document = DomDocument->loadHTML($someHTML);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($document);
//
//do some xpath query and processing
//
$result = $document->saveHTML();
$result = str_replace ('@nbsp;', '&nbsp;', $result);
```

Comment: I just found a cleaner approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59868319/586823