# saveHTML() doesn't output special characters properly

Tags: php, character-encoding, domdocument

I've looked at other answers ([php: using DomDocument whenever I try to write UTF-8 it writes the hexadecimal notation of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575109/php-using-domdocument-whenever-i-try-to-write-utf-8-it-writes-the-hexadecimal-n), [DOMDocument->saveHTML() converting &nbsp; to space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114627/domdocument-savehtml-converting-nbsp-to-space)) and either they don't apply to my situation, or I'm not understanding them.

I'm feeding some HTML into `$dom` like this...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($table_data_for_db);
```

I then do some stuff with it, then output it like this..

```
$table_data_for_db = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $table_data_for_db;
```

The problem is that special characters such as `&rarr;` end up like this `â†’`.

1.) Is there a way around this?

2.) Is there another way in PHP other than using `DOMDocument`, `loadHTML`, etc. to strip out sections of HTML?  Like, if I want to remove `<style id="fraction_class">` and all of its contents, is there another way?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use regex... `$table_data_for_db = preg_replace_all('/<style id="fraction_class">.*?</style>/', '', $table_data_for_db);`

Comment: @Siguza: Yeah... that's the conclusion I came to.  I'll leave this open for now if anyone has any creative ideas, but it seems to be a limitation ATM.

Comment: Generally when you have output that looks like `â†’` it means you have an encoding mismatch. `DOMDocument` is the best way to go for manipulating DOM elements, regex is a really bad way to go about it. What is the encoding in PHP, your server encoding, the encoding declared in your markup, and if you are retrieving the output from a database the database encoding and database driver encoding?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas: Sorry, but I don't know about any of that, but I got this from my phpinfo file.

iconv.input_encoding ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-1

Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575109/php-using-domdocument-whenever-i-try-to-write-utf-8-it-writes-the-hexadecimal-n

Comment: That may be part of the issue.  Assuming you refer to `&rarr;` as the literal character it represents and not the string for the html entity you need to use a character set that supports that character, generally one of the UTF variants. The right arrow does not belong to the `ISO-8859-1` character set.

Comment: @Lashane that's literally one of the ones referenced in the question asking how it can apply if it does.

Comment: @SteveBuzonas: I'm not sure how to do that.  Have any advice?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas you already mentioned that it could be something with encodings, I'm posting this link to emphasize where OP should look again

Comment: @gtilflm https://stackoverflow.com/q/1344692